# pass random variable to agg function python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame in `python` I am doing a `groupby` and `agg` on one of the column like below. In this `agg` I am dividing the `count` by a `specified number`. Now I want to pass a random number to divide the count value.

```
 df.groupby('a').agg(count('a')/3)
```

I want Something like this

```
 df.groupby('a').agg(count('a')/{}.format(random_number)
```

Can we do that?

Comment: `agg(count('a')/random_number)`?

Comment: @Aran-fey `count('a')` is not a builtin func

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need:

```
df['a'].value_counts() / 3
```

Solutions with `groupby` and `agg`:

```
df.groupby('a').agg({'a': 'count'}) / 3

df.groupby('a').agg({'a': lambda x: x.count() / 3})

df.groupby('a')['a'].agg(lambda x: x.count() / 3)
```

For random numbers per groups divide by numbers between 1 and 10, not between 0 and 10 for avoid `0` division (then get `inf`) by [`numpy.random.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3],
    'b': list(range(9))
})
print (df)
   a  b
0  1  0
1  1  1
2  1  2
3  2  3
4  2  4
5  3  5
6  3  6
7  3  7
8  3  8

df1 = df.groupby('a')['a'].agg(lambda x: x.count() / np.random.randint(1, 10))
print (df1)
a
1    0.500000
2    0.285714
3    0.500000
Name: a, dtype: float64
```